# Top bar review queue pending count vanished

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, design

Has there been a change, or has something broken to remove the pending review queue totals from the top bar button?

We used to get something like this;

[image: review queue totals from top bar - working]

But for maybe the last week (Not been online much) its changed and now shows up like this;

[image: review queue totals from top bar - gone]

Personally I liked the numbers, it gave an indication as to how busy the queues where at a glance from the page your on, rather than having to navigate into the actual queue page (which still shows the pending posts)

Didn't notice anything recent on meta, is this something that can be changed back to display the numbers?

Comment: Thanks - didn't find that post :)

Comment: As indicated by duplicate, this is a currently running A/B test.